# MDPI template remove line numbering

Tags: mdpi, numeration

I have a template for MPDI articles, and I would like to remove the line numbers as shown in the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We don't have your template, so we don't know how the line numbers got there.  But my guess would be that (1) if you look through the template, there will be a comment about the line numbers and (2) MPDI wants you to leave the line numbers there.  If either of those is incorrect, please create a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that shows how you get the line numbers.

Comment: The MDPI template has the class options `submit` and `accept`. If `submit` is used then there will be line numbers, if `accept` is used then the line numbers are removed. However, with the `accept` option the class tries to insert a logo for the journal name that you have selected. The journal logos are not provided with the template. This makes sense because the `accept` option is meant to be used by MDPI themselves, not by the authors (as mentioned in a comment in the `template.tex` file). So you either need to provide a dummy image for the logo or keep the line numbers.